# Screen keeps turning on

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I have a new Nexus 6 which immediately updated to Lollipop. When in standby mode the screen turns on randomly and displays the clock. This has been going on since I got it 24 hours ago.

Any thoughts or tips to fix this issue?

Comment: It might be [daydreaming](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2818748). Did the screen turn on when you charge or dock the phone?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. No, it is just sitting still. No charging.

Comment: I turned off daydreaming. Still happenjng. Very strange.

Comment: I had also this problem. but I found a solution with easy way. did you check for wakeup triggers in Wakelock Detector? the app requires root.

Answer (score 7):

After having switched off the Ambient display the problem has stopped for me. Hope this helps.

Settings > Display > Ambient display (Wake screen when you pick up device or receive notifications)

Answer (score 2):

You can try by going to `Developer options` and then disable the `Stay awake`check-box. ("Screen will never sleep while charging")